# How to retry a Vertex Pipeline step

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

In many cases, I want to allow Vertex Pipeline tasks to automatically retry on failures.
Is there anyway I can set the retry policy for the task?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
Pipeline task allows you to set the retry policy

```
set_retry(num_retries: int, backoff_duration: str | None = None, backoff_factor: float | None = None, backoff_max_duration: str | None = None) → PipelineTask
```

For example,

```
task.set_retry(2)
```

For a comprehensive document about the policy, see https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/master/source/dsl.html#kfp.dsl.PipelineTask.set_retry